# Joining 2 columns together

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've got some output data in a dataframe that looks like:

```
Region             Temp   Date
NEW ENGLAND        0      05-Apr
MIDDLE ATLANTIC    1      05-Apr
E N CENTRAL        1      05-Apr
W N CENTRAL        9      05-Apr
.
.
.
NEW ENGLAND        5      06-Apr
MIDDLE ATLANTIC    7      06-Apr
.
.
.
```

The *Region* repeats itself for each *Date* but I want to organize it so that it looks like:

```
   NEW ENGLAND Temp   MIDDLE ATLANTIC Temp......    Date
    0                         1                     05-Apr
    5                         7                     06-Apr
    .
    .
    .
```

Is there  a way to merge on or groupby the entire frame to get this format?

Comment: slice the dataframe then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe